# SOAP web service returns data on and off

Tags: java, web-services, iis, networking, soap

My source system provides SOAP url (hosted in IIS server) which we use it to get data, but lately we cannot pull data where it fails with nothing more than this msg in my side
"org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: SOAP message MUST NOT contain a Document Type Declaration(DTD)"
 
When the issue was debugged on the other side we got the following error
DEBUG httpclient.333.content [main] << "   [0x9]

IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.

"

The team that developed this service too cannot provide us anything useful info like where their app fails or any other useful info. A bizzare scenario occurs every now and then, wherein a data pull is successful in a test server but fails in prod server even when both of them point to the same SOAP url.

Everything worked fine as long as they hosted it in Apache tomcat, things worsened after they moved to IIS.

I want to know what settings to be looked at to resolve the issue.